iTerm 3.5 & Bash 5.2 prompt "shifting" where cursor shifts to right and is partially invisible
An odd issue I'm seeing with iTerm 3.5.10 and a Raspberry Pi 5 running Debian Bookworm 64-bit.
I'm ssh'd in using iTerm and if I have a relatively long command in my command history, hitting the up-arrow to get to the previous command, the long command shifts the prompt to the right about 10 characters or so with the command partially hidden behind the previous characters in the long command. Here's a gif demonstrating the behavior:

If I SSH into an older Raspberry Pi with an older version of bash (e.g. 5.0.3), I don't get the same behavior. Both have the same .bashrc file.
The Prompt is the default one that comes in .bashrc:
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ echo $PS1
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w \$\[\033[00m\]

A co-worker first told me about the issue. He was seeing it when pasting in a long command, the shifting thing happened almost immediately on paste. He tends to use arrow-keys to move about the prompt. But I was able to reproduce it without pasting and instead using vi-commandline-editing.
I tried unchecking the "Terminal may enable paste bracketing", but that hasn't made a difference. This is a relatively simple iTerm setup. Not much customization at all aside from  colors.

BTW, first posted in StackOverflow, but was directed here instead.

There was actually an error in the prompt definition. ChatGPT o1 figured that out for me.
It was missing an escape sequence:
Original:
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w \$\[\033[00m\]

Working:
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w \$\[\033[00m\]

Right after the second \u@\h it's missing a \[.
